# Phonegap build set splash screen location in config.xml

Tags: android, xml, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm playing around with trying to set a splash screen for phonegap using the config.xml to point to a png in my www folder.

Is this possible and if sure am I missing a step out? Do I need to put any javascript in my index.html to use this method.

I'm using phonegap build so I can't work out another way of easily putting on spalshscreen

Thanks

Sample config.xml

```
 <gap:splash src="assets/www/img/Now_Loading.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="assets/www/img/Now_Loading.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="assets/www/img/Now_Loading.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="assets/www/img/Now_Loading.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By www folder do you mean your root folder? The same location where you index.html is located? If so, you can do the following:

```
<gap:splash src="ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
```

I would really recommend creating a folder for your splash screen images and doing something like so:

```
<gap:splash src="splashScreensFolder/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
```

where your folder structure would look like:

-index.html

-splashScreensFolder

--ldpi.png

Additionally, you are going to want to create different resolution and size splashscreen's for the different resolutions you are specifying. Or, you can just use the below to reference one file for all resolutions/sizes:

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
```

In this case though, the png file will need to be located in the root of your project (same location as your index.html.

Comment: Ahh perfect - it only flashes up - How do I get it to stay up until the app is ready for use?

Comment: For android, you can set the duration by using `<preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="10000"/>` where value is in milliseconds. You can not control the duration on iOS.

Comment: it says malformed config xml when i put this line